# How to run npm command of a different package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

How to run npm command of a different package in my node_modules.

---

The only option I see is running a local script that will run a CLI command that will be the npm script of my different package... that's ugly and has a lot of edge cases to deal with (stream the output, cross-os compatibilities,...).

Comment: This depends on the type of the lib, if the lib has bin, you can run it using `npx lib-name`

Comment: Could you add some more information to the question? Like what package, or the reason you want to do this?

Comment: @Tim 1) a package that I create to do some node OS stuff. 2) it will be too long and I' want to keep this question general unless there is a good reason for not to do that.

Comment: @felixmosh I would like to run a specific npm script inside that lib's package.json. so I'm not sure how will that help. can you explain?

Comment: You can add a `bin` property to your package.json file that will point to the file that you want to expose via cli invoke, for more info https://medium.com/netscape/a-guide-to-create-a-nodejs-command-line-package-c2166ad0452e